Can't delete EventBridge trigger on AWS Lambda when there's function URLs
I got an error Unable to determine service/operation name to be authorized, when I tried to delete AWS Lambda function trigger, which is "EventBridge (CloudWatch Events)", if there's a function URLs set.
Error Image
Unable to determine service/operation name to be authorized
I found that I can delete the trigger by deleting that trigger's "Resource-based policy statements" first.
(Configuration -> Permissions -> delete "Resource-based policy statements")
Why does this happen?
How to reproduce

Create a lambda function (Python 3.12)
Create function URL (Auth Type = NONE)
Add a trigger "EventBridge (CloudWatch Events)"
Try to remove the trigger

FYI

The EventBridge rule exists (not deleted).
I googled delete aws lambda trigger "Unable to determine service/operation name to be authorized". I asked ChatGPT. But no related information found.

result of aws lambda get-policy
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "default",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "lambda-0c2959e8-a9d9-5fde-a89c-c46045280f76",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "events.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:999999999999:function:test",
            "Condition": {
                "ArnLike": {
                    "AWS:SourceArn": "arn:aws:events:us-west-2:999999999999:rule/Every10min"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "FunctionURLAllowPublicAccess",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunctionUrl",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:999999999999:function:test",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "lambda:FunctionUrlAuthType": "NONE"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}

